# Reading from a CryptoStream results in a padding error

Tags: c#, stream, cryptography

I'm writing an Aes decryption method and currently, I'm stuck on trying to read all the contents inside my CryptoStream and put it all into a byte[]. This is what I have for decryption:

```
    public byte[] GetDecrypted()
    {
        byte[] toReturn;
        using (Aes dec = Aes.Create())
        {
            dec.Key = Key;
            dec.IV = IV;

            ICryptoTransform cryptoTransform = dec.CreateDecryptor(dec.Key, dec.IV);
            using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(Data))
            {
                using (CryptoStream cs = new CryptoStream(ms, cryptoTransform, CryptoStreamMode.Read))
                {
                    using (MemoryStream decMs = new MemoryStream())
                    {
                        cs.CopyTo(decMs);
                        toReturn = decMs.ToArray();
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        return toReturn;
    }
```

For encryption, I used very similar code; maybe something's wrong here:

```
    public byte[] GetEncrypted()
    {
        byte[] toReturn;
        using (Aes enc = Aes.Create())
        {
            enc.Key = Key;
            enc.GenerateIV();
            IV = enc.IV;

            ICryptoTransform cryptoTransform = enc.CreateEncryptor(enc.Key, enc.IV);
            using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
            {
                using (CryptoStream cs = new CryptoStream(ms, cryptoTransform, CryptoStreamMode.Write))
                {
                    cs.Write(Data, 0, Data.Length);
                    toReturn = ms.ToArray();
                }
            }
        }
        return toReturn;
    }
```

Comment: It's quite possible that the issue lies in your encryption method, please also include the code you use to encrypt.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem indeed lies in your encrypt side. You must close the crypto stream to flush the data out to the underlying stream first. It is a easy fix, just move your `.ToArray()` outside of `CryptoStream`'s using block.

```
using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
{
    using (CryptoStream cs = new CryptoStream(ms, cryptoTransform, CryptoStreamMode.Write))
    {
        cs.Write(Data, 0, Data.Length);
    }

    toReturn = ms.ToArray();
}
```

Comment: Indeed that was the answer, something as simple as flushing the stream. Thank you very much!